# Pool pump plug trips when GFCI outlet receives power

Tags: electrical, gfci, pool

I have a GFCI outlet out by my pool. I have a timer switch inside that sends power to that outlet. My pool pump has a plug that is GFCI (I assume that is what a plug is called it has a test and reset button). Whenever my timer switch sends power to the GFCU outlet my pool plug GFCI trips. Push the reset and everything is fine. Unplug it and plug it back in works fine no problems. The only time it trips is when it is plugged in and the GFCI outlet receives power.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: How old is the GFCI? How old is the pump?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds highly unusual some plug mounted gfci s need to be reset whenever they receive power but as you said you can unplug it and plug it in without having to reset it so I would check the wiring at the switch to make sure that it is breaking the hot wire and not the neutral also make sure the bare ground wire is not contacting the neutral at the outlet or in the switch box.

Answer (score 0):

Your exterior outlet ***is*** GFCI protected so just (void the warranty) cut the plug off the pump and [put](http://www.familyhandyman.com/electrical/repair/extension-cord-repair/view-all) one of these on it.

[image]

---

The [Field Test Survey Task Force](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:anuCxmZ-jNwJ:forums.mikeholt.com/attachment.php%3Fattachmentid%3D2258%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) examined 2,680 GFCIs installed in 1,090 residences in ten locations within the United States. The task force completed the study and this is the [report of the findings](http://www.mikeholt.com/documents/freestuff/NEMA-GFCI-Field-Test-Survey-Report-January-2001.pdf). The task force has **not attempted to draw conclusions** on the results of the study but rather to report the results of the findings.

~Their findings? Sometimes **GFCI's fail**. (gee, thanks guys...)